# Python SyntaxError?

Tags: python

I am learning a tutorial for Python language and trying to write a basic "Hello World!" program.

But when I do all steps described in the book I receive an error.

```
>> print "Hello World!"

SyntaxError: Missing parentheses in call to 'print'
```

Why I am getting this error?

Is my book wrong?

Comment: You use Python 3 and the book is for Python 2. Change one of both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your book is right, but might be outdated a bit. It seems it describes Python version 2, but you try to run your example on the version 3.

Python 3 has changed some features and this one is the most annoying to switch from P2 to P3.

"print" statement changed to `function` rather than `operator` as was in P2.

Calling function you should always use parentheses.

So, if you want to run your program in Python3 you should call it:

```
print("Hello World!")
```

And that's it.

If you want to use examples from your book as is - install Python2 and it should work.

Comment: Oh my, so many answers within 5 minutes! I'll accept this one, but thanks to everyone!

Answer (score 2):

it seems that you're using Python 3.x.

In python 3.x, the print statement is a function and you need to use it as a function like this

`print("Hello World!")`

Comment: "the print statement is a function" -> And thus, is not a statement